# PriorityQueue order is not correct JAVA

Tags: java, priority-queue

I do have a `User` class which implements Comparable. After I add list of users into `PriorityQueue<User>` they should be prioritized by `scores`, but for some reason they don't. Could you please help me to figure out why users are not sorted in my `Queue`?

Update:

I am accessing queue by polling elements. `prioritisedUsers.poll()` it always comes with random scores with order respect.

```
PriorityQueue<User> prioritisedUsers = userPriorityStrategy.computeUserPriority(users);

while(!prioritisedUsers.isEmpty()){
    System.out.println(prioritisedUsers.poll().getPriorityScore());
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
0.35036433736768735
0.6619121139678329
0.09520067929838127
0.4013591573863
0.6704568389588227
0.5989900926939181
0.7320779721160738
```

Thanks for any help!

```
public class User implements Comparable<User>{

    private long id;
    private String fistName;
    private String lastName;
    private double priorityScore;

    public User (long id, String firstName, String lastName){
        this.id = id;
        this.fistName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public double getPriorityScore(){
        return this.priorityScore;
    }

    public void setPriorityScore(double priorityScore){
        this.priorityScore = priorityScore;
    }

    public long getId(){
        return this.id;
    }

    public String getFistName(){
        return this.fistName;
    }

    public String getLastName(){
        return this.lastName;
    }

    public int compareTo(User o) {
        return (int) (this.getPriorityScore() - o.getPriorityScore());
    }
}


    public PriorityQueue<User> computeUserPriority(List<User> users) {
        PriorityQueue<User> prioritisedUsers = new PriorityQueue<User>(users.size());
        for (User user : users) {
            user.setPriorityScore(rand.nextDouble());
            prioritisedUsers.add(user);
        }
        return prioritisedUsers;
    }
```

Comment: I run evaluate query in my IDE `prioritisedUsers.poll()` it always comes with random scores.

Comment: My bad, you are correct. 1+

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not so sure that your cast to (int) works well... because casting to an int implicitly drops any decimal.

If I'm not in wrong, try something like

```
public int compareTo(User object) {
if (this.getPriorityScore() < object.getPriorityScore())
    return -1;
if (this.getPriorityScore() == object.getPriorityScore())
    return 0;
return 1;
}
```

or alternatively and more simply:

```
public int compareTo(User o) {
    return Double.compare(this.getPriorityScore(), o.getPriorityScore());
}
```

Comment: Yep! 1+. Or more simply do `return Double.compare(priorityScore, o.priorityScore);`

Comment: Yes... better (+1)... Consider mine just as a didactical approach for better problem explaination...

Comment: I hope you don't mind but I added it as an edit to your answer.